# Are notebooks accessible on the spark as a service file system?

Tags: dsx, data-science-experience

I would like to investigate if it is possible to use the git command line client using a `%%sh` cell so that I can work directly with project resources such as scripts and notebooks using a git client.  E.g.

```
%%sh
git clone ... myproj
```

Are the dsx notebooks stored on the spark as a service file system?  If so, what folder are they stored in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notebooks are managed and are stored seperately and .ipynb are not exposed directly because DSX need ability organize this notebooks in project and collaborative enivornment.

You can certainly use

`%%sh`

`git clone https://github.com/charles2588/bluemixsparknotebooks`

Since the .ipynb files are not exposed, you cannot push them from here.
The alternative would be to use github integration and push files as explained in this thread:-
http://datascience.ibm.com/blog/github-integration-available-2/

Thanks,

Charles.

Comment: The github integration is really nice, but now I want more git!!  I would like to be able to manage my whole project with git, including notebooks and scripts.  See https://datascix.uservoice.com/forums/387207-general/suggestions/17836447-provide-much-more-git-functionality